# jCarousel Resizing Issue with Show/Hide List Elements

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

Is it possible to show/hide list elements within a jCarousel without loosing the scroll button behavior? I can dynamically add the elements but need more work.

I tried to set a dynamic width for the 'UL', but scroll button not getting disabled.

Here is the sample code which I created using basic sample of jCarousel.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-us"> 
<head> 
<title>jCarousel Examples</title> 
<link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<!--
  jQuery library
--> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/lib/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
<!--
  jCarousel library
--> 
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script> 
<!--
  jCarousel skin stylesheet
--> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/skins/tango/skin.css" /> 

<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var carouselObj;
        jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({ itemLoadCallback: mycarousel_itemLoadCallback });

        $("a#lnkHiddenRows").click(function () {
            $("ul#mycarousel li.hiddenRow").hide();
            carouselObj.visible = 3;
            $("ul#mycarousel").css("width", "280px");
            //carouselObj.size = 4;
            //carouselObj.reload();
            //carouselObj.setup();
        });

        $("a#lnkAllRows").click(function () {
            $("ul#mycarousel li.hiddenRow").show();
        });

        function mycarousel_itemLoadCallback(carousel, state) {
            carouselObj = carousel;
        };

    });

</script> 

</head> 
<body> 
<div id="wrap"> 
  <h1>jCarousel</h1> 
  <h2>Hide and Show jCarousel List Items.</h2> 

  <h3>Simple carousel</h3> 

  <a href="#" id="lnkHiddenRows">Show Hidden Rows Only</a> <br />
  <a href="#" id="lnkAllRows">Show All</a>

  <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango"> 
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/66/199481236_dc98b5abb3_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li> 
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/75/199481072_b4a0d09597_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li> 
    <li class="hiddenRow"><img src="http://static.flickr.com/57/199481087_33ae73a8de_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li> 
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/77/199481108_4359e6b971_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li> 
    <li class="hiddenRow"><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481143_3c148d9dd3_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li> 
    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/72/199481203_ad4cdcf109_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li> 
    <li class="hiddenRow"><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481218_264ce20da0_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li> 
    <li class="hiddenRow"><img src="http://static.flickr.com/69/199481255_fdfe885f87_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li> 
    <li class="hiddenRow"><img src="http://static.flickr.com/60/199480111_87d4cb3e38_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li> 
    <li class="hiddenRow"><img src="http://static.flickr.com/70/229228324_08223b70fa_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li> 
  </ul> 

</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Just as a comment, we ended up using easySlider. I had many problems with jCarousel, one of'em was, huge size. easySlider is almost 2 kilobytes.

Comment: If you see the jcarousel.js file then you will find that the enabling and disabling of next/prev buttons are calcuated with the lenth of the slides. So you have to modify the jcarousel.js file accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Saeed, We cannot migrate to easySlider now as we are near to the deadline, but sure I will give a try.

Comment: @a5his - I will add these items dynamically which will solve all the issues rather than modifying the plugin. We had a bad experience with a modified plugin updated by a newer version breaks the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same problem and below is the solution which make the jcarousel working.

Actually the jcarousel bind the slider to all the list items available in the slider wrapper so we just need to change something in the plugin  file "jquery.jcarousel.js".

(1)

At line number 255 replace this line
  return this.list().children();

With

return this.list().children('li.show'); OR  return this.list().find('li.show');

(2) Add a class "show" in list item (li) so it will include only that item in the slider.

Comment: You can also replace  return this.list().children();          with                                                                  return this.list().children(':visible');